# Jammit does not loads assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, jammit

I'm developing the web site using Aptana 2.04.

When i say "script/server" from the project folder, everything is ok

After copying the project folder to another place, and saying "script/server", server starts, but jammit does't loads the packaged assets and i see the web page without any css and js files loaded.

I played a little with this problem, and found following:

- When i say "jammit" from the non-copied folder, it packages the assets.
- When i say "jammit" from the copied folder, i get an error "Jammit Warning: No assets match" for each .js and .css file

Whats wrong here ?
Help !

---

Update 1

I refer to each asset in "assets.yml" in follwing way:

```
javascripts:
  common:
    - my_styles.css
```

my_styles.css are in "public/assets" folder.

I also tried "- public/assets/my_styles.css", but it does't work

---

Update 2

All works in production and development modes, when i starting the server from my project folder.

But, when i **just copy** the project folder to some other place, i get the jammit errors. Two folders are the same byte by byte, but the behaviour is different. This is what confuses me ...

Comment: Are you starting the server in `production` environment? by default, jammit doesn't request the minified assets in `development` enviroment, try with `production` and let us know :P.

Comment: Yes, see update 2 in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like you're referring to your assets properly -- Jammit will *cache* packaged assets into the `public/assets` folder -- the files shouldn't be in there to start with. Here's an example directory structure and assets.yml for you:

Directories:

```
public
  javascripts
    script1.js
    script2.js
    script3.js
```

assets.yml:

```
javascripts:
  common:
    - public/javascripts/*.js
```

Hope that helps you out. In development, you should see all scripts included as individual tag, and in production, you should see a single `assets/common.js` file.